# Sequelize TypeError: results.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using a sequelize raw query to archive records from my current "record" table to my archival table "archived_records". The query runs and successfully inserts the records into the archival table, but for some reason it always goes into my catch block and throws the error TypeError: results.map is not a function.

Here's what the query looks like

```
 const [results, metadata] = await sequelize.query('insert into archived_records select * from record where letter_sent <= "' + newdate + '";', {
            type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
        })
```

The value for newdate variable is: 2022-12-12

Comment: You execute INSERT and indicated SELECT type of a query, change it to INSERT as well

Comment: @Anatoly thanks, changing the QueryType from SELECT to INSERT is the solution. No more errors are being thrown.